# ES6 - How to declare implicit class member?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, jsdoc

If class members created from some options, how to declare them?

```
class cls {

    constructor(options) {

        Object.assign(this, {
            arr: [],
        }, options);

        this.arr[0] = 1; // <- IDE thinks that arr is an unresolved variable
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of an IDE problem than a code/language problem. Your IDE apparently can't statically determine that the code in the constructor will create an `arr` property on the instance.

Comment: *IDE* - which one?

Comment: I am using PhpStorm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for class property that wasn't explicitly defined to be recognized by IDE (Jetbrains PhpStorm/WebStorm), it's possible to specify a member with JSDoc:

```
class cls {
    /**
     @name cls#arr
     @type Array
     */

    constructor(options) {...}
}
```

Since property assignment with `Object.assign` doesn't provide additional benefits, a more natural way is to explicitly define a property explicitly on `this` (as other answers mention).

In ES6:

```
class cls {
   constructor(options) {
        this.arr = [];

        Object.assign(this, options);

        this.arr[0] = 1;
    }
}
```

In ES.next with [class field proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/), requires stage 3 (or lower) preset in Babel:

```
class cls {
   arr = [];

   constructor(options) {
        Object.assign(this, options);

        this.arr[0] = 1;
    }
}
```

Class fields are evaluated before constructor body, ES.next option is syntactic sugar for ES6 option. These two options are identical and recognized by IDE.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Babel, you can use a [class property](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) instead:

```
class cls {
    arr = []
    constructor(options) {
        Object.assign(this, options);
        this.arr[0] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: [The proposal is here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), currently Stage 3. It...has a very checkered history, but *this part* of it is likely to be stable. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What do you mean?

Comment: By "checkered history"? It's been one proposal, two separate proposals, three separate proposals at one time I believe, recombined again, gone from Stage 3 back to Stage 2 back to Stage 3, etc., etc. The history of what is now the current proposal is probably one of the most tortuous of any proposal since the new process was put in place (probably at least partially because it was one of the early ones).

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `Object.assign` for creating the properties with their default values. Write

```
class cls {
    constructor(options) {
        this.arr = [];
        Object.assign(this, options);
        this.arr[0] = 1; // should work now
    }
}
```